# Same IN (binds) multiple times in a query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to rewrite `WHERE a IN (<listA>) OR b IN (<listA>)` so I don't have to use `<listA>` (list of values I bind against the query) twice or more.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that.  You could, however, do this:

```
with listA as (
      select 'item1' as item union all
      select 'item2' union all
      . . .
      select 'itemn'
     )
select t.*
from table t
where a in (select item from listA) or
      b in (select item from listA);
```

The expression `in (<listA>)` probably won't do what you expect anyway.  If the value is `'1,2,3'`, then this constitutes a list with one element (`'1,2,3'`), not a list with three elements.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Regarding the `listA`, it would only be `'1,2,3'` if I was setting it as a string. Using `?` for instance (for all the items in the list) would solve that, but I'd have to bind the values multiple times.

Comment: Even better, using `with`, the `IN` (along with the inner selects can be removed): `with list as (SELECT 1 item UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) SELECT r.* FROM table r, list l WHERE r.a=l.item or r.b=l.item`